# wordpress `.htaccess` Rewrite rule except one folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want put some files in the folder `wordpress/crontab/` make some cron job. So I need all the files under `wordpress/crontab/` can run well and not pointed into a `404 page`. Here is the Rewrite rule in wordpress `.htaccess`, how to add some line that allow folder `wordpress/crontab/` out off the rule? Thanks.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: CJ, which URL are you trying to access from your browser that leads you to the 404 page?

Comment: @kovshenin, for example. I put `text.php` in `wordpress/crontab/`, then type `localhost/wordpress/crontab/text.php` it return a `404 page` I do not know why. so I think `Rewrite rule` limit the link.

Comment: Where's your wp-config.php located and where's the index.php file? I assume you installed WordPress into a directory? What's the url of your homepage and what's the url of wp-content?

Comment: the rules you have there, especially `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should prevent rewriting if you're accessing a file that exists physically in the path.

Comment: What @kb said is right, seems like you should be accessing localhost/crontab/text.php instead, because of the rewritebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I'll post this as an answer too:

What @kb said (in the comments) is right, seems like you should be accessing `localhost/crontab/text.php` instead, because of the `RewriteBase` set to `/wordpress/`

Cheers.

Comment: right, this is where the problem is. thanks two of u.